# Asseration Failed, Trying to make a Histogram in C++

Tags: c++, opencv

This is only part of the code, but I know the error is in here. Specifically this line :

```
float y = hist.at<float>(0,i);
```

For some reason my histogram is 0 by 0.

So the actual error is likely from how I used the calcHist() function

```
void entropyImage(string filename) {
Mat YCbCrImage, hist , image = imread(filename, IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
float range[] = { 0, 256 };
const float* histRange = { range };
int histSize = 256;

if (image.channels() == 1){
    double H = 0;
    //GrayScale Image
    calcHist(&image, 1, 0, Mat(), hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, true, false);

    for (int i = 0; i<histSize; i++){
        float y = hist.at<float>(0,i);
        cout << "symbol: " << i << "    was repeated: " << y << endl;
    }
}}
```

Here's how I'm calling the function from the main:

```
entropyImage("C:\\Users\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\lenagray.jpg");
```

Can someone more experienced in OpenCV let me know why my CalcHist isn't working"

Comment: That image path does not look correct (the user name is missing). Add a check for `image.data` to see if the image was read correctly.

Comment: Nope, I'm definitely opening something. I can print the image using: image.at<uchar>(i,j)

Answer (score 0):

- Just give channel by declaring array like,

  ```
  int channel[] = {0};
  ```

  and

  ```
  calcHist(&image, 1, channel, Mat(), hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, true, false);
  ```
- May be this will solve your probolem.